"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" we calculating phase angle of transfer funciton
I am calculating the transfer function and want to come up with a general equation for the angle of the numerator and denominator. The code for the angle of the denominator causes an error that says "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object." Please take a look and let me know how I can get around this error.
!pip install lcapy
!pip install folium
!pip instalpdflatex
!sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended
!sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
!sudo apt install dvipng
from lcapy import *
import lcapy
#from lcapy import s, expr
#from IPython.display import display, Math
from sympy import Symbol
#from sympy import I, re, im

cct = Circuit("""
R 1 2
C 2 0""")
H = cct.transfer(1, 0, 2, 0)

print("H =",H)
H=H(jw).simplify()
print("H(jw) =",H)

H_num, H_den = H.as_numer_denom()  # Extract numerator and denominator

H_num_real = re(H_num)
H_num_imag = im(H_num)
print("num_real:",H_num_real)
print("num_imag:", H_num_imag)
H_den_real = re(H_den)
H_den_imag = im(H_den)
print("den_real:",H_den_real)
print("den_imag:", H_den_imag)
num_phase = atan2(H_num_imag, H_num_real)
print("num_phase=",num_phase)
den_phase = atan2(H_den_imag,H_den_real)

commnenting out the last line causes the code to work and uncommenting it will spawn an error.
I tried the atan2() function and I was expecting a neatly defined expression.
output:
H=((1/(C*R))/(s + 1/(C*R)))*1
H(jw)=1/(j*C*R*omega + 1)
num_real:1
num_imag:0
den_real:1
den_imag:C*R*omega
num_phase:0


Is there any chance H_den_real is set to zero?  If so, atan2() probably wouldn't like that.

no. i updated my post with the output. i included the phase for the numerator. everything is fine and dandy but once we try and compute the denominator, all hell breaks loose.

For us to be able to help you, we really need a [mcve].  There are at least 5 undefined names in the code you posted, and you didn't include the full error traceback which might have at least allowed us to guess at the source of the problem.

I updated it. I did this in colab on google. it should be easy for anyone to try it.

What “neatly-defined expression” were you expecting?

Where is atan2 imported from?

@hpaulj atan2 is implicitly imported from lcapy

@coder The code, as shown in the question, runs without error in an up-to-date Python environment

I was expecting the arc tangent of the denominator's im/re and once i get that, i can get an expression for the overall angle of the transfer funciton.

@SIGHUP what python environment are you running the code on? Colab is throwing error for me.

@coder macOS 15.0.1, Python 3.13.0

I concur with SIGHUP. If you add the line print("den_phase=",den_phase) then the output is den_phase= atan(C*R*omega). But I'm not running in colab, where I suspect the error lies.
